# navigation drawer how to add image view above list view

Tags: android, listview, navigation, imageview, drawer

I am working on app where I need navigation drawer .I used the code of google to develop Navigation drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#6495ED"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

by this i get a navigation drawer ,but i want to put a imageview above list view .I googled it but i dont get of my means

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want?

Comment: you can add headerView to ListView

Comment: @Skizo i want to design a navigation drawer in which i want to show user image and name and after that a listview .. i know how to display listview but dont know how to add image view and textview in navigation drawer .i already show my code above about my navigation drawer that i have took from google developer site.

Comment: @virendrao by this the problem will not solve bro.. bcz that will show only header to list view

Comment: why it wont solve please elaborate... you can make custom listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can add a HeaderView to list by this the userImage will come above the listView like that 
     ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerview,  mDrawerList,false);

```
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```